# Browser not previewing image that was previously uploaded

Tags: reactjs, image

I have a component in React that is responsible for image preview. I also have an option for removing the image. I have noticed that if I have uploaded an image, and then removed it, that I can't preview it if I want to upload it again. Why is that happening?
This is my component:

```
class MediaPlaceholder extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      fileUrl: null
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      fileUrl: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0])
    })
  }

  removeImage() {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      URL.revokeObjectURL(prevState.fileUrl);
      return {fileUrl: null};
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {classes} = this.props;
    const {fileUrl} = this.state;
    return (
      <Paper className={classes.media}>
        {fileUrl &&
          <div className={classes.imageWrapper}>
            <IconButton aria-label="Clear" className={classes.iconButton} onClick={() => this.removeImage()}>
              <ClearIcon/>
            </IconButton>
            <img src={fileUrl} className={classes.image}/>
          </div>
        }
          <input
            accept="image/*"
            className={classes.input}
            id="upload-file"
            type="file"
            onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event)}
          />
          <label htmlFor="upload-file">
            <Button component="span">
              Add media...
            </Button>
          </label>
      </Paper>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This needs more details. What are the steps you perform to reproduce the issue? Are there any entries in the Browser console log? Can you provide an [mcve]?

Comment: The Remove Button only removes the preview image. It doesn't change the content of the input control. So, my guess is that the onChange event is not triggered because nothing actually changes if you select the same image again.